pTemplate body infer type for single item
Say we have template like this in angular which is using primeng p-table:
<p-table [value]="items" >
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <tr>
    <th></th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-item>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
 </p-table>

In the *.ts code we could have something like this:
items: customType[] = []

When I hover over the [value]="items" in the template I can see it is of type customType[].
When I hover over the let-item it tells me it is of type any. Is there a way to specify the type since it is not inferred?

You could just try  with *ngIf to define a new variable (as syntax), this variable will get its type from a function which will return the type you want
html
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-item>
    <tr *ngIf="setType(item) as typedItem">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>

ts
setType(item): customType {
    return item as customType;
}

In stackblitz its not suggested the types of html variables!
